# One selection only in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selection

I'm having problem to find solution to make a single selection row in the listview in my WPF application.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx)`="Single"`?

Answer (score 29):

The answer above is for ListBox, not ListView .

For a ListView you set the [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.multiselect.aspx) property to False (can be done via the Designer).

Comment: The question is tagged as **WPF**, you talk about **Windows Forms**. In WPF `ListView` inherits from `ListBox` and hence has the same property `SelectionMode`.

Comment: For WinForms THIS is the only way that's correct, not the top answer. This works for each framework, and thus is the better answer. Thanks James.

Comment: FWIW: @Ryan - however, it does NOT work in a WPF ListView. That's an entirely different class...

Answer (score 8):

ListView in WPF has **SelectionMode="Single"** .